# How to apply left join on two JSON objects in groovy script

Tags: json, string, groovy

I have two JSON files:

first.json

```
[
{"a":"1", "b": "tmp"},
{"a":"2", "b": "tmp"},
{"a":"3", "b": "tmp"}
]
```

second.json

```
[
{"c":"1", "d": "tmp"},
{"c":"2", "d": "tmp"},
{"c":"4", "d": "tmp"}
]
```

output.json

```
[
{"a":"1", "b": "tmp", "c": "1" , "d": "tmp"},
{"a":"2", "b": "tmp", "c": "2" , "d": "tmp"},
{"a":"3", "b": "tmp", "c": "" , "d": ""}
]
```

I want to apply left join on two json files first.json and second.json on basis of two fields - "a" of first.json and "c" of second.json to get the output as output.json. How can I achieve the same using Groovy Script?

NOTE: I would like to achieve this in a single line if possible.

Comment: @B001ᛦ I can’t find any Join method in groovy, I was trying to say that If there is a solution using groovy I would like to do the same in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do something like this:

```
def firstJson = '''[
    {"a":"1", "b": "tmp"},
    {"a":"2", "b": "tmp"},
    {"a":"3", "b": "tmp"}
]'''

def secondJson = '''[
    {"c":"1", "d": "tmp"},
    {"c":"2", "d": "tmp"},
    {"c":"4", "d": "tmp"}
]'''

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def slurpy = new JsonSlurper()

def first = slurpy.parseText(firstJson)
def second = slurpy.parseText(secondJson)

def result = first.collect { f ->
    f + (second.find { it.c == f.a } ?: second[0].keySet().collectEntries { [it, ''] })
}

println JsonOutput.toJson(result)
```